# Custominzation of fields in Redmine

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

I have two customize field in issue page of Redmine.

Say CF1 and CF2.
CF1 have list type and CF2 also have list type.

suppose CF2 have content like user1, user2.

And the condition is, if I select user2 from CF2 then CF1 should be visible.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand the CF1 is going to be visible when you select a User in CF2 and probably show values relating to the User which is selected.
You have to develop a little plugin to do so. Cause you need some extra logic to do so.

To see what you can do with custom fields see: 
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineCustomFields

---

See how to connect Redmine with Upwork: www.redmineupwork.com